Как узнать, где посмотреть что за строчку хранит к примеру %05d
-media_seg_name "$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$"

К примеру один из параметров в команде %05d. Это порядковый номер сегмента. Другой параметр
%01d Тоже порядковый номер...
Где посмотреть, какое число, что содержит. К примеру мне необходима высота кадра текущего сегмента...

01 и 05 всего лишь задают количество цифр, а число во всех случаях одно и то же

Хорошо, тогда есть ли возможность в процессе. Узнать высоту кадра текущего сегмента. Хотел бы сегменты рассортировать по папкам относительно высоты их кадра.
